# .git/refs/heads not getting all branches

Tags: git, github, azure-devops, azure-repos

When I run .git/refs/heads, it shows only the branches that I have checked out locally.
How can I create refs/heads to all my branches?
Or how can I create refs/heads to all the origin/?

I am working with Azure DevOps. I am using their predefined variables that will ONLY return the branch ref of the source/target of the Pull request. However, those variables will return, for example, refs/heads/feature. So after I am getting the refs, I am using git rev-list $branch-ref in one of my devops tasks. But it giving me the ambiguous argument 'refs/heads/feature': unknown revision ERROR. I think that is happening because the git checkout that is happening does not have those references. However, when I use origin/feature it works fine. So I am trying to find a way that I turn all origin/ into refs/heads/

Comment: You shouldn't need to make local branches for all of origin. You can reference `origin/branch_name` if you just need to read the branch. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `.git/refs` folder, you find:

- **`heads` folder**, containing all the refs of local branches
- **`remotes` folder**, containing all the remotes (ex. `origin`)
- **`remotes/origin` folder**, containing all the refs of the `origin` remote branches
- **`tags` folder**, containing all the refs of tags

In case the repository has been packed, which may occur automatically, you'll find the references into the file `.git/packed-refs`.

Depending on your needs, the correct way of extracting the references is through `git` itself.
Accessing the raw `.git` files should be avoided.

Comment: They do not contain all the references. Some will be in [packfiles](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery).

Comment: As soon as the repo won't be packed, they do contain all the references. Anyway I agree with you that accessing the raw .git files should be avoided

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clearer. I appreciate your answer, but I think now you will have a better idea on what I want.

Answer (score 1):

`.git/refs/heads` will not contain a list of all your local branches. Some will be in [`.git/packed-refs`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery).

To see all your local branches, use [`git branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch).

> How can I create refs/heads to all my branches?  Or how can I create refs/heads to all the origin/?

You shouldn't make a local branch unless you intend to make modifications. You can instead refer to the [remote tracking branch](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches). `origin/foo` refers to the branch `foo` on `origin`.

If you really want to, write a little script using `git branch -r` to get a list of all your remote branches. Here's an example in Ruby.

```
remotes = `git branch -r`.split("\n").map(&:strip)
locals = remotes.map { |r| r.sub(%r{^.?+/}, ''); }
remotes.zip(locals) { |r,l| system("git branch #{l} #{r}") }
```

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clearer. I appreciate your answer, but I think now you will have a better idea on what I want.

Comment: @MSOUFAN If you want the source and target of a PR, that will be your remote tracking branches. If it says refs/heads/feature that is the remote's feature branch which is your origin/feature, not your local feature. Again, there's no need to make a local branch unless you plan on making commits you're going to keep.